# Prevent new line on hit Enter Key on MudField (MudBlazor) in blazor application

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have **blazor webassembly** application that uses **MudBlazor** for the UI, and on razor page i have **MudField** inside a MudForm , and when the use hit the Enter key the cursor goes to the newline, i would like to prevent from going on newline on Enter key and only when the user hit Shift+Enter then it should go on new line.
Here is what my markup looks like:

```
<MudForm Class="d-flex flex-grow-1 px-4" SubmitOnEnter="true">
            <MudTextField T="string" Placeholder="@Localizer["Enter your message..."]" @bind-Value="@MyChatState.CurrentMessage" Immediate="true"
                          DisableUnderLine="true" Lines="2" Margin=Margin.Dense Clearable="true"
                          Variant="Variant.Outlined" Validation="@(_validator.ValidateFieldsAsync)" OnKeyDown="HandleKeyDown" />
```

```
@code {
        protected async Task HandleKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == "Enter")
            {
                
                e.preventDefault() //This only works in JS
                
               //Send the message to the API 
            }
        }
               
     }
```

I know the way it is done in javascript with **e.preventDefault()** but i don't know how to achieve the same behavior in blazor. I would appreciate any help.
Thank you

Comment: What is the UX reasoning for disallowing Enter but allowing Shift+Enter, while allowing multiple lines in your text box?

Comment: all text boxes i have used so far allow Shitf+Enter and multiple lines but when you hit the Enter key the form is submitted but the cursor doesn't go on new line.
You can do experiment with the Stackoverflow comment box if you wish

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jetdog for pointing out the `KeyDownPreventDefault` property of the [`<MudTextField>`](https://mudblazor.com/api/textfield#properties)...

```razor
<MudForm Class="d-flex flex-grow-1 px-4" SubmitOnEnter="true">
    <MudTextField
        T="string"
        Immediate="true"
        DisableUnderLine="true"
        Lines="2"
        Margin=Margin.Dense
        Clearable="true"
        Variant="Variant.Outlined"
        OnKeyDown="HandleKeyDown"
        KeyDownPreventDefault="_preventDefault" />
</MudForm>

@code {
    bool _preventDefault;

    protected void HandleKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        _preventDefault = e.Key == "Enter" && !e.ShiftKey;
    }
}
```

[Click here to have a play with the code above in TryMudBlazor](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GYmHvFwvonBXftjK)

---

Original answer using `div` wrapper workaround instead of `KeyDownPreventDefault`...

A way of doing this is shown here: [How to use event.PreventDefault in Blazor](https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-use-event-preventdefault-in-blazor.htm)

However, the above approach does not appear to be supported by MudBlazor yet. But there is a way if you wrap your `<MudTextField>` in a `<div @onkeydown:preventDefault...>` like this...

```razor
<MudForm... >
    <div @onkeydown:preventDefault="_preventDefault">
        <MudTextField... />
    </div>
</MudForm>
```

[Click here to see the full div wrapper code in TryMudBlazor](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GuwHOSaQfuHkadEY)

Comment: This is useful, but the MudTextField does provide KeyDownPreventDefault property so you don't need to add a div.